# APIGEE -- generate documentation from XML wadl?

Tags: xml, rest, documentation, documentation-generation

I have an APIGEE .wadl file I'd like to generate REST documenattion from for all the API requests.  Has anybody done this, or am I stuck with writing my own parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible yet.  Built my own html parser instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of examples using xslt:

- https://github.com/mnot/wadl_stylesheets/
- http://wiki.openstack.org/Documentation/APISite (produces this site: http://api.openstack.org/)